# simplify a string excluding an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove every extra spaces, signs, and lowercase ( in another words I want to simplify) the string with a function. The following function does this perfectly:

```js
console.log(simplify('   The     very optiMal! FUNCTION, {here] ...'));

function simplify(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9'_]+/g, " ").trim();
}
```

But the issue is I want to exclude an array of signs not to be removed from the string:

```
const signs = ['!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':'];
```

So if the is any of the above signs in the string it should be intact and not be removed.

How would you do this?

Comment: Why does the OP not make such additional characters part of the already existing negated/excluding character class?

Comment: Have you tried to do it with regex as you are doing in the function? You can add a condition and check for those symbols with regex.

Comment: you have 1-2-3 dots in your exclude list. How about four dots? Or 100 dots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
const signs = ['!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':'];
const exclusion = signs.map(x => x.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|");
const regex = new RegExp("(" + exclusion + ")|(?:(?!" + exclusion +")[^A-Za-z0-9'_])+", "g");

function simplify(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase().replace(regex, (x,y) => y || " ").trim();
}

console.log(simplify('   The     very optiMal! FUNCTION, {here] ...'));
```

*Details*:

- `(<exclusion>)` - Group 1 with exclusion patterns
- `|` - or
- `(?:(?!<exclusion>)[^A-Za-z0-9'_])+` - a char other than an ASCII alphanumeric, underscore or `'` chars, one or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start any of the exclusion patterns (since some of them are multi-character they cannot be simply included to the original negated character class).

The replacement is the Group 1 contents if Group 1 matches, else, the replacement is a space.

Another way to approach the issue - in case you want to always have a space separating each substring - is to use a reverse approach: match what you need and then join with a space:

```js
const signs = ['!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':'];
const exclusion = signs.map(x => x.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|");
const regex = new RegExp(exclusion + "|[A-Za-z0-9'_]+", "g");

function simplify(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase().match(regex).join(" ");
}

console.log(simplify('this is...'));
```

Comment: Bravo, Still trying to understand this, too complicated for me..

Comment: I don't get it and unable to make it work for my needs,  let's try this, what if I want to to have one space between each sign in the array and the normal text so if input is `this is...` the output would be `this is ...`  ??

Comment: @SaraRee You probably want `return string.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp("(?:" + exclusion + "|[A-Za-z0-9'_])+", "g")).join(" ");`

Comment: I did something near this but it doesn't do it

Comment: @SaraRee Ok, see the second snippet that I have just updated.

Comment: LEGENDARY..  Thanks a lot .. now is time to learn...